Most comprehensive online directory of U.S. campgrounds?
What is the most comprehensive directory of campgrounds for the United States?

According to AlternativeTo.net,

ReserveAmerica is the largest provider of campsite reservations in North America facilitating millions of transactions every year.

However, FreeCampsites.net lists free, pay, and permit campsites, many of which are not listed on ReserveAmerica.

And recreation.gov is very useful. To be clear, are you associated with either site you’ve mentioned?

@JonCuster No, I'm not affiliated with either.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
